# Is it possible to return to Skuldafn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just completed the main quest, but when I initially got to Skuldafn Temple I became over-encumbered and dumped all my inventory into a dragon corpse hoping I could come back to retrieve it later (since there wasn't a way to leave Skuldafn and I didn't want to load an older save to dump all my stuff before going there). I dumped a whole ton of valuable stuff like dragon bones and various special weapons, armour etc.

Now I'm back in Skyrim and there doesn't seem to be a way to get back there to retrieve all my gear.

I would be willing to use console commands now that I have completed the main quest without any kind of help. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get back there without console commands. The console command you are looking for is "coc " and you'll probably need to do it again to get out.

Use `coc skuldafn02` to get there. The codes for Skuldafn are `skuldafn01` trough `skuldafn04`. 02 should put your back in the Skuldafn temple. `coc whiterun` might bring you back home. Not sure about the last one.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. The relevent codes are 'skuldafn01' through 'skuldafn04'.

Comment: You have to type xmmm before you type your destination into the sub hub box &mdash; including the x,y,z position, as character models may be corrupted and not indexed correctly!

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to get to Skuldafn/Sovengarde after the main quest by using `coc skuldafn02` in the console

Answer (score 3):

Several mods exist on various platforms that allow one to return to Skuldafn.  How it's done in game varies from mod-to-mod.

For Skyrim Special Edition on Nexus we have [Fly to Skuldafn](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/14370) by [candoran2](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/users/4180069)
which allows one to ride a dragon (for example Odahviing) back.

The description for this mod states:

> This mod allows you to return to Skuldafn on the back of any tamed dragon, Odahviing or Durnehviir once you've finished the main questline. Also allows you to get the unique dragon priest staff or return to Sovngarde.

On Bethesda Net, we have a mod called Return to Skuldafn by [Darth_Mew](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?author_username=Darth_Mew) which is available for:  [PC](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4071848), [XBox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4071858), and [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4072187).  (Yes, that's right, a mod that's available for the PS4.)  This one works by enabling it as a fast travel location.  The description for this mod states:

> This mod allows you to return to Skuldafn and the ancient portal that resides there, the portal to the Nordic afterlife.