# Is there any way to get back to Skuldafn without using the console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to return to Skuldafn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38240/is-it-possible-to-return-to-skuldafn)

Is there anyway to get back to Skuldafn once completing that quest without using a console command (since I'm on the Xbox 360 version)?

Comment: Unless the other question can be expanded to have a console specific answer, not sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: The console-specific answer is "no".

Comment: @kotekzot No, is still a valid answer. If it's correct, then post an answer.

Comment: I have to agree with Doozer that this isn't a duplicate, as the other question specifically relies on console commands unavailable to the Xbox version. As such, I'm voting to reopen this as a valid question.

Comment: The other question now has a console specific answer, so unfortunately this *has* become a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible on a console, but you may be able to [transfer the Xbox save to a PC](http://justpressstart.net/?p=5650) and teleport yourself there via the developer console with `coc Skuldafn01`, then move the save back to the Xbox. You may have to use that method again to get back to Tamriel.