# Would it be possible for Paarthurnax to take the Dragonborn to Skuldafn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Spoilers on the main quest:

> When the Dragonborn captures Odahviihg, he learns that Alduin's portal to Sovngarde is on Skuldafn, on the Jeroll Mountains on the far east of Skyrim. Wouldn't it be more wise to keep a untrusted dragon captured and go to Skuldafn with a dragon he already trusts ?

I don't know if It's possible, or if Paarthurnax tells the dragonborn why he doesn't or can't bring him to Skuldafn, does someone has any information about this or a lore-reason for this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to return to Skuldafn?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38240/is-it-possible-to-return-to-skuldafn)

Comment: Close voters: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate of [Is it possible to return to Skuldafn?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38240/is-it-possible-to-return-to-skuldafn) This seems to be more of a lore question about Paarthurnax, and/or how to go to Skuldafn by riding Paarthurnax, specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't kill him on the Blade's mission, yes, he probably could lore-wise. In game this can't happen. Maybe with a mod.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in the game you might have accepted and completed a quest from the Blades telling you to kill Paarthurnax. This would make it impossible for you to go to Skuldafn then.

So, yes, he could, but only if he could, in which case he wouldn't.

Comment: I received the quest to kill him, yes, but when he gave me his reason for not to kill him, he conviced me, and so I didn't kill him.

By the way, after learning from Odaahviing the location of the portal, I tried talking to Parthurnaax and there wasn't any dialogue option, so, at least on game mechanics it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for Paarthurnax to not do this is that (especially after the fight at the throat of the world) he is well known as an enemy to Alduin; he would be attacked on sight if he comes anywhere near Skuldafn.Fighting Alduin's allies without dropping the dragonborn would be tricky.